# Why @Cacheable didn't work when used in controller and interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

springboot 1.5

main

```java
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan(value = {"com.spring15.mapper", "com.spring15.cache.mapper"})
public class LearnMainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(LearnMainApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

controller

```
@PostMapping("/emp/get")
//@Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#id", condition = "#id>0", unless = "#result == null")
public Employee getEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){
  logger.info("====== get ======");
  return cacheService.getEmp(employee.getId());
}
```

mybatis's mapper

```java
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    @Select("select * from employee where id = #{id}")
    Employee getEmployeeById(Integer id);

    //@CachePut(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Update("update employee set id = #{id}, lastName = #{lastName}, email = #{email}, dId = #{dId}, gender = #{gender} where id = #{id}")
    int updateEmp(Employee employee);

    //@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Delete("delete from employee where id = #{id}")
    int deleteEmp(Integer id);

    //@Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Insert("insert into employee(lastName, email, dId, gender) values(#{lastName}, #{email}, #{dId}, #{gender})")
    int insertEmp(Employee employee);

}
```

service

```java
@Service
// @CacheConfig(cacheNames ="employee")
public class CacheService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    //@Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#id", condition = "#id>0", unless = "#result == null")
    public Employee getEmp(Integer id){
        return employeeMapper.getEmployeeById(id);
    }
}
```

Sent post request by Postman then got below results:

`@Cacheable` used in service

got employee's data from cache for the second time.

```java
@Service
// @CacheConfig(cacheNames ="employee")
public class CacheService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#id", condition = "#id>0", unless = "#result == null")
    public Employee getEmp(Integer id){
        return employeeMapper.getEmployeeById(id);
    }
}
```

`@Cacheable` used in controller

Always got employee's data from DB.
`@Cacheable` didn't work.

```java
@PostMapping("/emp/get")
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#id", condition = "#id>0", unless = "#result == null")
public Employee getEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){
logger.info("====== get ======");
return cacheService.getEmp(employee.getId());
}
```

`@Cacheable` used in mapper

Always got employee's data from DB.
`@Cacheable` didn't work.

```java
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#a0", condition = "#id>0", unless = "#result == null")
    @Select("select * from employee where id = #{id}")
    Employee getEmployeeById(Integer id);

    //@CachePut(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Update("update employee set id = #{id}, lastName = #{lastName}, email = #{email}, dId = #{dId}, gender = #{gender} where id = #{id}")
    int updateEmp(Employee employee);

    //@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Delete("delete from employee where id = #{id}")
    int deleteEmp(Integer id);

    //@Cacheable(cacheNames = "employee")
    @Insert("insert into employee(lastName, email, dId, gender) values(#{lastName}, #{email}, #{dId}, #{gender})")
    int insertEmp(Employee employee);

}
```

Why? And What are their differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public Employee getEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){
  logger.info("====== get ======");
  return cacheService.getEmp(employee.getId());
}
```

For the controller, the method signature doesn't contain an `id` as parameter, so the `@Cacheable` will not work because of a missing cache-key. It has an `Employee` as a parameter not an `int id`. So the cache-key should be `#employee.id` to use the proper cache-key.

The MyBatis mapper isn't managed by Spring but by MyBatis, adding Spring Annotations to a non-Spring managed bean will result in nothing being applied.  That and instead of caching an `Employee` it would cache an update count (the `int` return value) with the `Employee` as the key, not the value.